# When will an android service recreate?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

As far as I know, a service will get recreated when it is,

1. Started as `START_STICKY` for intra process
2. Or with `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` for inter process
3. Or service is declared with `persistent=true` (specially for system apps)

In all these cases, is that true that unless or until the service is started in one of (1) or (2) ways? If no one is there to start the service via (1) or (2) will still (3) be able to start the service since it is started with persistent flag?